# Loading chars into dynamically allocated 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, char, dynamic-memory-allocation

This might be one of the common questions, but all solutions I've seen so far are not working.
I want to dynamically allocate 2D array of chars. I get these chars from a .txt file. I even have set number of rows (int r) and columns (int s). Allocation itself is working but whenever I try to load chars from a file into this array, it crashes. Have no idea why.

File is ordered in this way:

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
```

Opening desired file:

```
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error occurred when loading the file, program quits now.");
        return 1;
    } else {
    printf("File loaded successfully.");
    }
```

Getting info about number of columns and rows (r are rows, s are columns):

```
    int r,s,i,j;
    char arrayInfo[6];
    fgets (arrayInfo, 6, file);
    char* comma = strchr(arrayInfo, ',');
    s = atoi(comma - 1)+1;
    r = atoi(comma + 1);
```

Memory allocation for a 2D array of chars:

```
    char **array = malloc(r * sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        array[i] = malloc(s * sizeof(char));
    }
```

**NOT WORKING** Loading of chars from a file and then printing them. This code would work with "char array [r][s];" instead of dynamic allocation.

```
    for (j=0;j<r;j++) {
        for (i=0;i<s;i++) {
            array[i][j] = fgetc (file);
        }
    }

    for (j=0;j<r;j++) {
        for (i=0;i<s;i++) {
            printf ("%c",array[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try switching your indices: use `array[j][i]` instead of `array[i][j]`.

Comment: Also, you should always verify that `malloc` doesn't return `NULL` (as it does if, for instance, you run out of memory). Unless you have large values of `r` and `s`, this probably won't matter, but it's good programming practice nonetheless.

Comment: Your code would become much simpler if you'd read the file line-by-line using the existing `getline` library function.

Comment: All `int`s in the snippets should really be `size_t`s. No need to negative indices.

Comment: Also `sizeof(char)` is redundant as `sizeof(char)` is definded to be equal `1`.

Comment: Also^2: To provide robust code use `char ** array = malloc(r * sizeof *array);` instead of `char **array = malloc(r * sizeof(char *));`

Comment: Unless you have some overriding need to read each line **character-by-character**, the generally preferred method for reading **lines** from a text file is to use **line-oriented-input** (e.g. `fgets` or  `getline`). You then parse the resulting line-buffer as needed. There is nothing wrong with **character-oriented-input**, you are just afforded a more robust set of features in the **line-oriented** functions.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a crash I doubt that issue is with:

```
array[i] = malloc(s * sizeof(char));
```

Please make sure whether malloc() succeeded or not first, later try to write to this allocated memory.

`a[i][j]` `i` is your row and `j` is your column. We see in your code it is interchanged.

I don't know how your file looks like but please re-check the below evaluation

```
s = atoi(comma - 1)+1; /* comma is a pointer and you are decrementing it by 1? */
```

`,` is being used in strchr and later the pointer is decremented by 1 to get the integer value which is not what you want. Fix this also.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input guys - array [i][j] needs to be changed to array[j][i], then it works as it should.